# SQL simple update returning an error

Tags: sql-server, oracle, update

Oracle SQL and Microsoft SQL Server:-

I have a single table in which I wish to set two 'USERFIELD' column values, for all rows having their other column values set to a given literal.

```
SET ESCAPE ON
UPDATE DOCUMENT
SET USERFIELD4 = 'Europe \& International', USERFIELD7 = 'E\&I Engineering'
WHERE DOCNO in 
   (SELECT d.DOCNO FROM DOCUMENT d 
    WHERE d.USERFIELD4 = 'Combat Air' 
      and d.USERFIELD3 = 'Engineering' 
      and d.WITHDRAWN=0)
```

DOCNO is the table unique key column.

So, what I want is that if for a given row, USERFIELD4 = 'Combat Air' and USERFIELD3 = 'Engineering' and WITHDRAWN=0, then for that same row, set USERFIELD4 to 'Europe & International' and set USERFIELD7 to 'E&I Engineering', and for this to apply to all rows in the table.

I am getting the following error:

> SQL Error: Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= or when the subquery is used as an expression.

Comment: I suspect `DOCUMENT` has a trigger and the error is happening there.

Comment: Nothing showing up in SQL workbench in the Triggers tab ??

Comment: EDIT: But there is if I interrogate sys.triggers:-

TR__DOCUMENT__AFTERUPDATE

any way round this?

Comment: `any way around this?` - yes, you need to fix the code in the trigger. If you show us that code we can help.

Comment: I suspect once we've peeled the layers of the onion away this could be a duplicate of [this question](https://dba.stackexchange.com/q/98991/1186). In my answer there I explain the flaw with triggers written with the assumption that the triggering action only ever affects one row, and one way to work around it.

Comment: Why is the question tagged with both Oracle and SQL Server?

Comment: because it occurs in both SQL Server and Oracle

Answer (score 1):

The issue was a poorly written QueryPlan in response to a defined Trigger as per @Aaron Bertrand presumed. I rewrote the QueryPlan to return more than one row which was what was causing the rather misleading error message.